# Image uploaded from Android photo to a Datasnap server has different image type and dimensions

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap, tstream

I am attempting to create a Delphi XE5 Android Datasnap application (regular, not REST) that uploads pics.

See the code below. The code works! The image taken by the camera on the Android phone gets transferred to the server and saved. The problems are:

1. the image that is saved to the server is recognised by IrfanView as a .png. After renaming image001.bmp to image001.png, it is viewable but
2. it is consistently 800 x 600
3. the photo is also automatically saved to the Android in the library/pictures/camera folder. This image is a .jpg, with a size of 1600 x 1200. It is not a .bmp or .png.

I'm confused. Where is all this automatic conversion taking place?

The client code looks like this

```
procedure TfrmMain.TakePhotoFromCamerAction1FinishTaking(Image: TBitMap)
var
  ImageStream: TMemoryStream;
  Bytes: Integer;
  FileName: String;
begin
  ImageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Image.SaveToStream(ImageStream);
    ImageStream.Position := 0;
    FileName := 'Image001.bmp';
    Bytes := ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.UploadImage(FileName, ImageStream);
    if Bytes = -1 then
       raise exception.create('Image transfer failed!')
  finally
    ImageStream.Free
  end;
end;
```

The method on the server looks like this

```
function TServerMethods1.UploadImage(FileName: String; Stream: TStream): Integer;
const
  BufSize = $F000;
var
  Mem: TMemoryStream;
  BytesRead: Integer;
  Buffer: PByte;
begin

  frmMain.LogMessage('Upload image ' + FileName);
  try
    Mem := TMemoryStream.Create;
    GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);
    try
      repeat
        BytesRead := Stream.Read(Buffer^, BufSize);
        if BytesRead > 0 then
          Mem.WriteBuffer(Buffer^, BytesRead);
      until BytesRead < BufSize;
      // here, replace with DB update
      // for now, save to file
      Mem.Seek(0, TseekOrigin.soBeginning); // necessary?
      Mem.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + FileName);
      // ============================
      Result := 1; // Mem.Size doesn't work...
    finally
      FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
      Mem.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := -1
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Two questions and a note: 1) Why are you uploading the file and providing a filename with a .bmp extension when Android saves it as a .jpg, instead of using a .jpg extension? 2) Why all the Buffer^ and TMemoryStream nonsense on the server, when you could simply create a TFileStream, use CopyFrom(Stream), and then free the TFileStream to save it? (The whole server side code would be about 10-12 lines of code). Note: AFAIK, Android doesn't support BMP images, because they're typically Windows only. IIRC, Android supports PNG and JPG natively. It's highly unlikely you're getting a BMP.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup wrt the bmp being a Windows format. Clearly the FMX code is doing the translate (and resize) to PNG then. Show me the code that would work with a TFileStream please!

Comment: Sure. `OutStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate); try OutStream.CopyFrom(Stream, Stream.Size); finally OutStream.Free; end;`

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately that code only replaces the `Mem.Seek` and the `Mem.savetofile` lines of my code. (and it's 6 lines, not 2)

Comment: I said "10-12 lines", so 6 is considerably less than that, I think. The code I posted replaces the call to GetMem, the entire repeat..until loop and the need to FreeMem, as well as removing the need for Buffer and BytesRead. It also removes the BuffSize constant.

Comment: No it doesn't! Note that this is a method on a DataSnap server. SO is full of advice on dealing with Stream parameters, and working in 32k chunks is clearly the way to make sure it works consistently with any filesize.